# Where can I find a GDAL distribution with DWG support?

Tags: gdal, open-source-gis, dwg

I want to use the GDAL utility *ogrinfo* with dwg files. Where can I find an GDAL distribution with a support for DWG files (read only)?

DWG support is moved out of the normal GDAL/OGR source distribution. I found [this documentation how to include DWG into ogrinfo](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DxfDwg). But I do not know how to build an executable from a source code. So I am looking for a “ready to use” distribution of gdal (ogrinfo) with DWG support.

Thanks

Jens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DWG is a proprietary format owned by Autodesk -> people aren't allowed to just reverse engeneeir it. 
I believe that the commercial teiga package  (what ogr uses for DWG support) requires licencing: [you have the pay a montly fee](https://www.opendesign.com/join) .
OSGEO can't include it in their distribution, only paying members can.

Mayby you can use their [converter](http://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/TeighaFileConverter) to convert you DWG to  DXF, this format is available in most versions of ogr/gdal

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to convert dwg to dxf. But I have hundreds of DWG files that I want to examine.

Comment: OK, if there are license fees, then I understand why I can not find a GDAL with DWG in the web.

Comment: The teiga converter can work recurse trough folders, so flag the checkbox recurse folder and just point to the top folder where your dwg's are stored  and write them to an output folder. This can take a while, but it is not manual work.

Answer (score 6):

I am not aware of a GDAL/OGR build available anywhere with DWG support enabled.  As noted, this depends on an SDK that requires non-trivially complex licensing arrangements.

If you really need it, you are best off joining the open design alliance and building it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It contains additional information. I marked the response of warrieka as a solution - unfortunately I can not mark two answers as the solution.

Answer (score -1):

I would try [OSGeo4W package](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/#QuickStartforOSGeo4WUsers), seems to have quite recent versions.

Comment: I tried OSGeo4W package. The DWG support is not included.