# ogr2ogr dwg CAD file to postgres

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr, cad

I am attempting to load a CAD .dwg file into a postgreSQL database using ogr2ogr.

this is the command

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL "PG:host=localhost user=postgres password=*** dbname=jaffe" C:\Users\blah\Desktop\SAMCO.dwg -s_srs EPSG:4326 -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom
```

get this error

```
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `C:\Users\blah\Desktop\SAMCO.dwg' with the following drivers.
```

what am I doing wrong?

EDIT

I realized the CAD file has no SRID number associated with it, could that cause the problem?

Comment: Do you have one of the required libraries installed? either https://github.com/sandyre/libopencad or Open Design Alliance Teiga library

Comment: i have windows and i need to install a library for this conversion using ogr2ogr?

Comment: Is `DWG` listed in `ogrinfo --formats|sort`? If not, you are out of luck. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42158/where-can-i-find-a-gdal-distribution-with-dwg-support

Comment: dang good call @AndreJ looks like im out of luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Where can I find a GDAL distribution with DWG support?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42158/where-can-i-find-a-gdal-distribution-with-dwg-support) you need to buy a license for the library that can support DWG in GDAL-based software.

For that reason, it is not included by default in GDAL builds.

There has been some work to overcome this last year: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DWG_driver, but it is not yet in OSGEO4W or Gisinternals builds.

At the moment, the best workaround is to save the file as DXF inside Autocad.