# CAD file creation in custom software

Tags: gdal, dxf, cad, dwg

I've worked a little with basic exporting of CAD .DXF files from our software using GDAL.  We want to do more sophisticated things, like importing and creating georeferenced files with multiple layers, and it is clear that GDAL's functionality around CAD formats is rather limited.  [Other questions like this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42158/where-can-i-find-a-gdal-distribution-with-dwg-support) address the lack of .DWG format support for various reasons (explained in more detail [at GDAL's website](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DWG_driver)).  There is good information about open source CAD software in other questions [like this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53760/open-source-cad-software).

Does anyone know of good open-source software libraries other than GDAL that have more sophisticated CAD file format reading and creation abilities we could use in our software to create .DXF or .DWG files?

Should such a library not exist, an alternative workflow like using file conversion sounds possible, like using FME to convert from different formats to CAD as discussed in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/which-gis-support-dxf-and-or-dwg).